# C# get focused window title of remote machine without installing agent on remote machine

Tags: c#, .net

I want to capture the title of currently focused window on target server. I tried wmi and other stuff too i can get what applications are running, when they were last accessed etc but not which of them is currently focused

Comment: How do you connect to the remote computer? Do you have a program running there?

Comment: No i don't have agent installed on target server.Usually i connect using wmi or psexec

Comment: If my exe would have been running on target then there was no problem at all i can get using  GetForegroundWindow() or ui.automationelement.current.focused method. But my problem i cant run my exe over target i need to achieve my goal without any exe running on target

Comment: Similar to this question as well, but the only proposed solution involves installing an agent on the remote machine.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11352618/c-sharp-get-main-window-title-of-processes-on-a-remote-machine?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Try getting a list of windows ([like this](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Enumerate-top-level-9aa9d7c1)) and then verify witch one is active.

Comment: i can get open process on target server thats not challenge.My problem is that i m not able to find out whether it is currently active.

Comment: Target machine runs your code (you made your own server) or are you connecting with some sort of service?

Comment: For example A person on remote machine opened cmd at 1 am but after wards the person minimized it and was working on something else. So here i want to find only time when he was working on cmd i.e start time and end time

Comment: No my goal is making a agentless solution